# Delphi 7 - Multiple else if does not display the right label

Tags: delphi, if-statement, conditional-statements, delphi-7

I'm trying to make a blood pressure category checker in Delphi 7, and I just got to know Delphi for a few weeks. The problem is every time I put numbers above than 120, the label caption always displaying normal.
Here is my code :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var a,b:real;
begin
a:=strtofloat(edit1.Text);
if (a<120) then label1.caption:='optimal'
else if (a>120) then label1.caption:='normal'
else if (a<130) then label1.caption:='normal'
else if (a>130) then label1.caption:='normal high'
else if (a<140) then label1.caption:='normal high'
else if (a>140) then label1.caption:='grade 1 hypertension'
else if (a<160) then label1.caption:='grade 1 hypertension'
else if (a>160) then label1.caption:='grade 2 hypertension'
else if (a<180) then label1.caption:='grade 2 hypertension'
else if (a>181) then label1.caption:='grade 3 hypertension'

end;

end.
```

It may be some common mistake but I still can't figure it out myself, any kind of help would help a lot, thank you.

Comment: The code would work properly if you *reversed* the order of the tests: first check whether > 180, then > 170, etc. The accepted answer with the case statement is the way to do this cleanly.

Comment: Either use integer and case, or reverse your test and start with  `a > 181` first because 150 is also greater then 120 and 130 and 140... so you never reach a test beyond `a > 120` in your logic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is incorrect. It only checks two values, which are `< 120` and `> 120`. Nothing else is ever tested.

When looking for a value within a range, you need to test for both ends of the range, like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
  a: real;
begin
  a:=strtofloat(edit1.Text);
  if (a < 120) then
    Label1.Caption := 'Optimal'
  else if (a >= 120) and (a < 130) then
    Label1.Caption := 'Normal'
  else if (a >= 130) and (a < 150) then
    Label1.Caption := 'Normal high'
  else if (a >= 150) and (a < 160) then
    Label1.Caption := 'Grade 1 hypertension'
  else if (a >= 160) and (a < 170) then
    Label1.Caption := 'Grade 2 hypertension'
  else if (a >= 170) and (a < 180) then
    Label1.Caption := 'Grade 3 hypertension'
  else
    Label1.Caption := 'Heart exploded from pressure';
end;
```

(Your ranges are all really confused. You'll need to adjust my code to meet your actual range requirements, but what I've posted should get you started.)

As it's unlikely that someone is going to record a blood pressure as a floating point value (not likely your BP is going to be 121.6/97.2), you probably want to use an integer instead, which would make the code easier.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  a: Integer;
begin
  a := StrToInt(Edit1.Text);
  case a of
    0..119:  Label1.Caption := 'Optimal';  // Probably want to test for too low
    120..129: Label1.Caption := 'Normal';
    130..149: Label1.Caption := 'Normal high';
    150..159: Label1.Caption := 'Grade 1 hypertension';
    160..169: Label1.Caption := 'Grade 2 hypertension';
  else
    Label1.Caption := 'Over 170! Danger!'
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Test (a> = ...) is not required because the lower limit is guaranteed by the previous if (a < ...) - not (a < …) = (a >= …) :)

Comment: If a=120 then there will be a third and final test

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - As I know 120 < 130 :). First test (a < 120) = false, second test (a < 130) = true, so second test is final test

Comment: When I read the problem, I also thought of using the `case` keyword. You beat me up by answering first. Great answer!

Comment: @branko I'm referring to the code in the question. When the input is 120 both of the first two tests fail.

Comment: @Branko: why don't you debug your code, follow the path taken and try with several inputs, say, 119, 120, 121, 122,  etc. You'll see that Ken is right. Your logic is off.

Comment: @Ken: while > 180 is not really healthy, the heart won't explode yet. <g>

Comment: @RudyVelthuis - You probably did not understand my comment. The logic in this code is certainly not off: 
`if (a < 120)      then Label1.Caption := 'Optimal
  else if (a < 130) then Label1.Caption := 'Normal'
  else if (a < 150) then Label1.Caption := 'Normal high'
  else if (a < 160) then Label1.Caption := 'Grade 1 hypertension'
  else if (a < 170) then Label1.Caption := 'Grade 2 hypertension'
  else if (a < 180) then Label1.Caption := 'Grade 3 hypertension'
  else Label1.Caption := 'Heart exploded from pressure';`

Comment: @Branko: yes, true. The >= tests are not necessary in Ken's code, because the `else` already takes care of that. I thought you were commenting on your original code.

Comment: @Ken Just a little nitpick, you are missing apostrophe in `Optimal` and `Grade 1 hypertension`.

Comment: As Branko pointed out, the >= conditions are unnecessary, and they also invite bugs if this code gets revised and the break points are changed. To express each break point, use only a single test, this way there can't be gaps. The second solution demonstrates the use of case where it is a bad solution. It requires using integers, which is not what the OP asked for, is not congruent with instruments that report with decimals, and again relies on two limits being coordinated for each breakpoint, thus prone to accidentally introducing gaps when revised.

Answer (score 2):

What does an `IF` statement do?  It checks the condition.  If the condition is `TRUE`, it executes the `THEN`-clause.  If the condition is `FALSE`, it executes the `ELSE`-clause, if there is one.

When you write a sequence of `IF`-`ELSE`-`IF`-`ELSE`-`IF`-`ELSE`-... there's nothing special going on.  The condition of the first `IF` is tested. If it's `TRUE`, it executes the `THEN`-clause, if not it continues to the `ELSE`-clause.  The `ELSE`-clause could contain *any* statement. It could be a `FOR` or a `WHILE` or an assignment or a function call or a `BEGIN`-`END` block, or any other statement.  In this case the `ELSE`-clause just happens to be another `IF` statement, and so that `IF`'s condition is checked, and so on.

In the end, you've written code that checks a number of conditions, and stops at the first condition that is `TRUE`.

Pick a value and trace through your code manually to see how it works.

Start with `a=100`.  The first `IF` asks is `100<120`. This is `TRUE` so it sets the `caption` to `'optimal'`.  The `ELSE`-clause is never executed,  All is well so far.

Start with `a=200`.  The first `IF` asks is `200<120`.  The answer is no, so execution passes to the `ELSE`-clause.  That `ELSE`-clause consists of an `IF` asking if `200>120`.  The answer is yes, so it sets the `caption` to `'normal'`.  This is not what you intended.

Consider `a=120`.  The first `IF` tries `120<120`.  That's `FALSE` so it goes on to the `ELSE`-clause.  There we find the `IF` asking is `120>120`.  That's also `FALSE`, so we pass through to the next `IF`.  That one asks is `120<130`.  That's `TRUE` so the `caption` is set to `'normal'`.

In fact, these examples show every possible path through your code.  None of the `IF`'s beyond are ever reached.

Here's an example that should work as you intended.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  a, b : real;
begin
  a := strtofloat(edit1.Text);

       if a < 120 then label1.caption := 'optimal'
  else if a < 130 then label1.caption := 'normal'
  else if a < 140 then label1.caption := 'normal high'
  else if a < 160 then label1.caption := 'grade 1 hypertension'
  else if a < 180 then label1.caption := 'grade 2 hypertension'
  else                 label1.caption := 'grade 3 hypertension'

end;
```

Be careful when selecting between  `<`  and  `<=` .  What do want to happen when `a` is exactly `120`?

Be careful to consider all possible values.  When you wrote your original code what did you intend should happen when `a=180.5`.  You have a condition for `<180`, and another for `>181`.  Values from `180` to `181` are being ignored.

Comment: FYI, your numeric ranges don't match those I found here: https://vascularcures.org/high-blood-pressure-and-vascular-disease/